# tortoiseSVN:Revision range to merge option ,why show this result?

Tags: svn, merge, tortoisesvn

### [image]

from branches to trunk
merge range :4-5,8

result:
[image]
why 7777,8888 show result ???
Yes what algorithm SVN? Or steps?

Answer (score 0):

IMHO

```
step 1:
merge 4-5 to trunk.

trunk = branch 5 = .... 777 888 999 101010

step 2:
merge branch differences (7-8) to 'new' trunk:

diff 777 -> 7777 applied to 777 => 7777
diff 888 -> 8888 applied to 888 => 8888
diff 9999 -> 9999 applied to 999 => 999 (because nothing for appy)
diff 1010 -> 1010 applied to 101010 => 101010 (again nothing different in 10th line from 7 to 8 revision, so in result this line not changed also)
```

About conflicted 333 I am not sure, but may be this line is too close to truly conflicting lines - 222? Try insert more context lines in test:

```
1
--
--
--
2
--
--
--
3
...
```

and check if 333 still conflicted.

Comment: Thank you very much for Sergey Azarkevich, thank god for someone to be able to read my question.
Sergey Azarkevich: I want to add, the question is why the revision is 7 "333" the corresponding revision is 8 "3333" is the conflict, and revision is 7 "777" the corresponding revision is 8 "7777" is not the conflict? Thank you thank you
I want to take the SVN merging algorithm is clear! Please help me!!!!!!!